# dictionary with df inside as value and changing column names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have the below dict with DataFrames inside as the value. I simply want to transpose the DataFrame, reset the index and rename the columns based on the key in the dict. It seems very simple, but the transpose and reset index do not work in place.

The code only works if I assign a variable to the result, for example
`value = value.T.reset_index(inplace=True)` but that defeats the point, as I want the original value (which is a DataFrame) in the dict to update.

```
df_dict = {'volume': vol_df, 'shares': shr_df, 'float': flt_df}

for key, value in df_dict.items():
    value.T.reset_index(inplace=True)
    value.rename(columns={value.columns[0]: 'bbg_ticker', value.columns[1]: key}, inplace=True)
```

Comment: The reason is that `value.T` already returns a copy, so `reset_index(inplace=True)` works on that copy, not on the original `value`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are modifying the DataFrame returned by `value.T` in-place, not `value` itself.

As far as I'm aware, transposes cannot be done in-place; this is probably because they completely restructure the DataFrame instead of just changing data or labels while keeping the structure largely the same.

There's nothing wrong with just setting the value at `key` to the new DataFrame; I'd recommend just doing that:

```py
for key, value in df_dict.items():
    value_T = value.T.reset_index()
    df_dict[key] = value_T.rename(
        columns={value_T.columns[0]: 'bbg_ticker', value_T.columns[1]: key}
    )
```

Comment: im confused by your last sentence, can you give an example please

Comment: @Zack I've updated my answer to hopefully be a bit clearer.

Comment: you sir are amazing! - thank you very much